# What is the policy (or how do you) make a post that shares something interesting but is not really a question?

Tags: discussion, scope

I came across a bit of information about a TV show that I find fascinating and wanted to share that with the community but its not a question, so I didn't want to "ask a question" and post it and be wrong or violate policy, so I wanted to ask here first, how would one go about doing that.

Basically there is no existing facility that I am familiar with where I can share a story about a TV show and something exciting being done with it in an unconventional manner. Can someone please kindly advise what I should do? I really want the community to know and I think it would promote debate and be interesting. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I took a leap and posted this questions, be kind but tell me what you think (https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/13704/what-are-the-lessons-from-the-walking-dead)

Comment: @ChristianRau, sorry about that extra tag, wasn't sure if this would be considered an FRE or not, thank you for the edit.

Comment: No offense but walking dead question appeared off topic to me and primarily opinion based witch doesn't fit in Q/A Format

Comment: @AnkitSharma, so I take it the negative feedback on the question came from you huh? I guess trying to put effort in getting it right wasn't dedication enough to make it relevant huh?

Comment: If the consensus is that its not worth it, doesn't add any value to the community, then I will be happy to delete it. @TylerShads, your thoughts?

Comment: The problem with the question is that it will become discussion rather then a question. And Movies and TV is a Q/A site not a discussion forum. I liked you question but it doesn't fit in this community. Rather then it will suit in a blog or our chatroom discussion etc.

Comment: I loved your dedication and efforts and love this kind of meta discussion where user want to get feedback. And i think your question could be turned into a good blog. But it's only my opinion and appreciate if others turned into your favor.

Comment: Well I went ahead and deleted the question since it was put on hold and it seemed that generally people didn't want it there. So self discipline and genuine care, I went ahead and deleted it. As suggested, I put it on a blog post on my site, hopefully that will gather some attention, or maybe just tumbleweeds, who knows. Maybe after I have taken the class I will have something more specific to ask or share. Thanks for everyone's input.

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ *"so I take it the negative feedback on the question came from you huh? I guess trying to put effort in getting it right wasn't dedication enough to make it relevant huh?"* - I have a hard time bringing this kind of response to *Ankit*'s objective arguments in relation with your otherwise great efforts and dedication for doing things right. Don't kindly ask for opinions about a question's validity only to feel personally offended when the community shows that the question doesn't fit here.

Comment: @ChristianRau, you misunderstood me. I wasn't offended, and I wasn't hitting back in anyway, its the problem with the text only medium. I was simply being playfully facetious. If anything I was being self deprecating and having a go at myself. I am sorry if it was taken any other way. See my reason for deleting the question, why would I criticize the comments when I asked for it and led to me doing what transpired in net effect?

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ Oh sorry, in such situations a simple *";)"* (or something similar) at the end of a comment can do wonders in removing the seriousness from a comment (even if some people still might have a problem getting that). At least as long as SE doesn't support [sartalics](http://glennmcanally.com/sarcastic/) yet.

Comment: @ChristianRau when you're right, you're right. I sometimes forget that just because I can hear it in my mind and know its intent, it doesn't always carry that way in print. Sartalics would certainly help that but doubt it will come since SE doesn't even support underline :(

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately the main site is not a forum - it is (as you have seen) a Q&A system, so only caters to asking and answering questions.

However ...we would welcome any discussion about movies and TV shows in chat.  Chat can sometimes be quite busy depending on the time of the day.  If you post something in there even when it is quiet it will get replied to at some point.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I appreciate that. I might do that but since I don't always stay online consistently through the day, I am afraid if I drop it and people discuss it and I am not there, it would considered rude, inconsiderate and I might miss out on something but this way I can track it, come back to it and you know, discuss. But I understand what you are saying. How about if it was phrased in a form of a question, since I do wonder about how valuable people think such things might be, so I can post the information in that context. Keep an eye open, let me think best way and in the morning post.

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ If you think it *might* be phrasable as a valid question but are not sure about it, a first start would be to put it on meta. Otherwise I don't think it's considered as rude in any way if you're not in chat to react on any discussion. You can always catch up later on things you might have missed in chat. Yet you also have to be aware of the fact that chat isn't really that active and there's no guarantee it will lead to an interesting discussion at all.

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ *"since I do wonder about how valuable people think such things might be, so I can post the information in that context."* - I'm not sure that would work, though, sounds like a *"give me your opinions on this"*-question, which doesn't fit that well. Unfortunately for some things there is just no platform in SE. I have millions of theories and analyses about my favourite movies, yet am bound to a question being asked in order to spill them out. That's just the way this site works.

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ Maybe you can also do a so-called "blog-overflow". Ask a question and provide the answer yourself right away. While I myself am not too fond of those types of questions (which to me sometimes seem a bit like self-adulation, even if not intended this way), they are definitely valid and on-topic, as long as the actual question is.

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ Dropping something in chat isn't considered rude at all.  It may take a while to ber eplied to depending on the current conversation (if there is one) but its th perfect place to just dump a topic, discuss (or not) and be on your merry way.

Comment: Thank you all for the helpful perspectives, I appreciate them all. @ChristianRau I am certainly not the self adulation type, so probably won't go that route, 90% of time I don't even propose an answer if I am not 100% convinced its "great" but merely good because I don't like to be derivative in any way; although with certain things, there is only so many ways to say something, so can't be helped. -TylerShads this is something I need to work on, I have always been of the principle "say it, own it, see it through" so I have to learn to adapt to dump and run :)

Comment: Ok everyone, be kind since I tried hard to do this right, posted this question (http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/13704/what-are-the-lessons-from-the-walking-dead) what you think?

Comment: I don't think it is self-adulation to ask and answer your own question, and in fact I believe it is encouraged in S/E. We are creating a library of questions and answers - it makes sense to add to the library if you have information that would be interesting to others.

Comment: @MaryJoFinch, understood, thank you. I will keep that in mind for future reference.